# Blender won't import FBX animations?

Tags: animation, rigging, import, keyframes, .fbx

What do I do if Blender won't import FBX animations?

I have a FBX file with a character that's animated. The mesh and rig imports correctly to Blender, however, the animation of the rig won't import. I can see that the file is, in fact, animated thanks to Autodesk's FBX Review-software. Keyframes are imported, however, the rig won't animate.

Any ideas?

*Feel free to download and experiment yourself: https://we.tl/t-gIrSEGp0Jq*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is two actions in the file. Switch to the other one in the Action Editor (Located in the DopeSheet panel).